# Collect transformed StateFlow in Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

There is function `collectAsState()` applicable to a `StateFlow` property in order to observe it in a `Composable`.

A composable requires a `StateFlow` because `StateFlow` guarantees an initial value. A `Flow` doesn't come with that guarantee.

Now, what is the way to go if I have a `StateFlow` property but I want to apply an operator (like `map`) before collecting the `Flow` in the `Composable`?

Here an example:

Let's say a repository exposes a `StateFlow<MyClass>`

```
val myClassStateFlow: StateFlow<MyClass>

data class MyClass(val a: String)
```

... and a view model has a dependency on the repository and wants to expose only the property `a` to its `Composable`...

```
val aFlow = myClassState.Flow.map { it.a } // <- this is of type Flow<String>
```

The `map` operator changes the type from `StateFlow<MyClass>` to `Flow<String>`.

1. Is it semantically justified that `aFlow` has no initial value anymore? After all its first emission is derived from the initial value of `myClassStateFlow`.
2. It's required to convert `Flow` back into `StateFlow` at some point. Which is the more idiomatic place for this?

   1. In the view model using `stateIn()`? How would the code look like?
   2. In the composable using `collectAsState(initial: MyClass)` and come up with an initial value (although `myClassStateFlow` had an initial value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2631)

Currently there is no built-in way to transform `StateFlow`s, only `Flow`s. But you can write your own.

Way I ended up solving was to use the example in that post.

First create a notion of a `DerivedStateFlow`.

```kotlin
class DerivedStateFlow<T>(
    private val getValue: () -> T,
    private val flow: Flow<T>
) : StateFlow<T> {

    override val replayCache: List<T>
        get () = listOf(value)

    override val value: T
        get () = getValue()

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
        flow.collect(collector)
    }
}
```

Then have an extension on `StateFlow` like the current `map` extension on `Flow`

```kotlin
fun <T1, R> StateFlow<T1>.mapState(transform: (a: T1) -> R): StateFlow<R> {
    return DerivedStateFlow(
        getValue = { transform(this.value) },
        flow = this.map { a -> transform(a) }
    )
}
```

Now in your Repository or ViewModel, you can use it as below.

```kotlin
class MyViewModel( ... ) {
    private val originalStateFlow:StateFlow<SomeT>  = ...
    
    val someStateFlowtoExposeToCompose = 
        originalStateFlow
        .mapState { item -> 
            yourTransform(item)
        }
}
```

Now you can consume it as you expect in Compose without any special work, since  it returns a `StateFlow`.